# Model binding a property attribute not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API.

I an endpoint which accepts a model called Search. It has property called Query of type Expression. This Expression object has sub classes.

```
public class Search {

public Expression Query{get;set;}
}

Public class Expression {
}

public class AndExpression {
  public IList<Expression> Expressions {get;set;}
}

public class MatchesExpression {
  public string FieldId {get;set;}
  public string Value {get;set;}
  public string Operator {get;set;}
}
```

I post the following JSON to my endpoint (content-type of application/json)

{
"query":
{
"fieldId": "body",
"value": "cake",
"operator": "matches"
}
}

Firstly, the query parameter is just the base Expression - A polymorphic issue!

So... I thought bespoke Model Binder.

I can set up a model binder against the Search object, but you'll note that the AndExpression can contain other Expression objects, so instead I'd like to write a binder that can be bound to "Query" on the Search Model and to Expressions on the AndExpression Model etc etc

I attempted this:

```
public class Search
{

    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(ExpressionBinder))]
    public Expression Query { get; set; }
}

  public class ExpressionBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }




   public class ExpressionBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider {
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }
    
            if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(Expression))
            {
                return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(ExpressionBinder));
            }
    
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Ive wired this binder up in the configureServices method of my Startup Class.

I have a break point in the ExpressionBinder and it doesn't hit!

What am I doing wrong?

Also, can I use the  [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(ExpressionBinder))] attribute against a list of Expressions?

Comment: This article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api seems to say  that the ModelBinder attribute cant be applied at the property level.

Comment: But this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0 says "You can apply the ModelBinder attribute to individual model properties" so its REALLY unclear what the best approach is here

Answer (score 4):

So this is very explicit https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4553

If a FromBody attribute is applied the ModelBinder attribute wont work!